# 'tar' command '--remove-files' option

Tags: tar, archive

If I am trying to archive files in loop using tar command with `--remove-files` option. If some exception occurs in mid of execution, will the `--remove-files` option delete the current operating file or retain the original file ?

```bsh
while read file; 
do
    tar -uf test.tar.gz --remove-files "$file"              
done
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as my experiments go (and somehow as I expected):

- the source file is removed only if the command completes normally
- however, "-u" doesn't remove the previous version of the file, it merely adds it to the end, so repeated updates with the same file will make the TAR file grow indefinitely.

Comment: I want to know status of source file which will be added in tar file.It will be deleted/retained ? if exception occurs in archiving the file.

Comment: As  I said the source file is retained if anything bad happens.